# Django - how to pass more than one primary key to the view

Tags: django, django-templates

I need to write a view to delete multiple objects in one go.
I have modified the HTML template, put checkboxes to select which objects (users) to delete and a button to delete them, but of course you need a view to perform the task.

When you have one item to select at a time, you pass its primary key to the view through the url, how can I extend this to pass more than one primary key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to send the data in a JSON format, which can easily be decoded by Django

On the frontend, you'd have a JavaScript for a button like so,

```
function delete_object(pks) {
    var args = {type: "POST", url: "/delete/", data: {'pks': pks}};
    $.ajax(args);
    return false;
}
```

this function would take selected the primary keys from (which is passed in as `pks`) and POST it to the Django url `^delete/$`. A Django view function can then handle the incoming data like so,

```
def delete(request):
    object_pks = request.POST['pks']
    Docs.objects.filter(pk__in=object_pks).delete()
```

Comment: Firstly, this isn't JSON but a simple POST. Secondly, the JS seems like overkill. Why bother when a form with a submit button will do the job just as well?

Comment: @DanielRoseman you are right that this may be a little over-engineered, and a simple submit button could work. In my view there're two advantages of using JS instead of a submit button: 1) the user does not need to be redirected to another webpage (AJAX makes the requests async). 2) you get a nice separation of the frontend view (displaying the form and the confirmation message) and the backend view (which does the actual deletion)

Answer (score 4):

You would absolutely not be doing this via the URL. If you have a set of checkboxes, then you have a form; since the form is doing destructive operations it will be submitted via POST: therefore your set of IDs is in `request.POST`.